# Why does my tensorflow logger output None or twice?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using the tensorflow high API `tf.estimator.Estimator`. If I doesn't set anything about logging. It outputs nothing. But if I set the `logging.basic_config like` that:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='[%(name)s] : %(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s',
                    level=logging.INFO)
```

Then it will output the info twice:

```
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 1040.93
[tensorflow] : 2018-03-28 22:21:47,788 : INFO : global_step/sec: 1040.93
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.027323281, step = 6026 (0.096 sec)
[tensorflow] : 2018-03-28 22:21:47,789 : INFO : loss = 0.027323281, step = 6026 (0.096 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 6075 into ./log\model.ckpt.
[tensorflow] : 2018-03-28 22:21:47,832 : INFO : Saving checkpoints for 6075 into ./log\model.ckpt.
```

It seems that there has two logger handlers, but I don't know how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is that close the python lib logging, and set the `verbosity` of `tf.logging` to info.

Note: the name of `set_level` in tf.logging is called `set_verbosity`.

```
tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)
```

If you want to use logger to show info, you should use `tf.logging.info()` ranther than `logging.info()`